# Problem involving Properties of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I am given two real functions $f$ and $g$ that are continuous on the interval $[a,b]$ such that for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, we have: $f(x)< g(x)$. The question is to prove that there exists a number $\epsilon  > 0$ such that: $f(x)+\epsilon \leq g(x)-\epsilon $ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

I tried to start from the definition of continuity of the functions $f$ and $g$, but I couldn't figure out how to find such an $\epsilon  > 0$. Any help please?

Comment: @AndréNicolas: There was a typo in the original statement. I edited the post now...

Comment: Edit the question some more, to assume strict inequality $f(x)<g(x)$.  With $\leq$ you could have $f(x)=g(x)$, and then the desired conclusion is false.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: I have just edited the original statement. Sorry for confusing everybody!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $h(x)=g(x)-f(x)$. Since $h(x)$ is continuous, it attains a minimum value $\delta \gt 0$ on our interval. Now let $\epsilon=\delta/3$.

Comment: Perhaps it should be better to explain why $\epsilon=\delta/3$ and not $\epsilon=\delta/2$.

Comment: It was just protection against the $\le$ changing to $\lt$, the posted question changed a few times.